# Android Live Camera

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

Hi i am able to capture single image and show it in an imageview from live camera, but how to capture multiple images from live camera and show them on imageview, Imageview should be genarated dynamically. Camera preview and Imageview should be in a same layout.

Comment: what do u mean by capture multiple img..can u clarify this more

Comment: Hi thank u for replying. I captured a single image from live camera and shown it on an imageview, both the cameras preview and image view are on same layout. But i want multiple imageviews. I want to capture first image and show that one on first imageview, when i capture second one it will be shown on second image view ans so on. The imageview should be generated dynamically.